# Ordering items in Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to order 5 items inside a container,

How much ever I try I'm not able to fit "Item 5" inside the container, it's overflowing.

I want it to fill the empty space in the container and stop overflowing.

**Here's the Code Snippet:**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  color: wheat;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.item-4 {
  background-color: rgb(155, 0, 96);
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

.item-5 {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex-item item-1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="flex-item item-2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="flex-item item-3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="flex-item item-4">Item 4</div>
    <div class="flex-item item-5">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture item-5 is overflowing the container, I want it to take the space left below item-2 and item-3.

Comment: _"I want it to take the space left below item-2 and item-3."_ - that is not really possible in `flexbox`, that is a row-based layout system. (Or column, depending on how you specify it. But it is mainly "one-axis only".) You need to go and look into `grid` layout instead.

Comment: I think that Item 5 cannot fill that gap because flex-wrap is create a track based on Item 1 height. Have you considered using grid instead? or if you still want to use, the easiest way is to add `margin-top: -50px;` to Item 5.

Answer (score 3):

It may sound weird, but you can use `margin-top` property and move the `item-5` `50px` to top as `item-1` has `200px`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  color: wheat;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.item-3 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.item-4 {
  background-color: rgb(155, 0, 96);
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
}

.item-5 {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="flex-item item-1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="flex-item item-2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="flex-item item-3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="flex-item item-4">Item 4</div>
    <div class="flex-item item-5">Item 5</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```